# Wordpress Related Posts via Category Outside Loop

Tags: wordpress, foreach

I found this snippet of code online and does what I need it to do which is give me a list of related posts via category outside the loop in the single template.

```
<?php
    $postid = $post->ID;
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
        echo "<h3>Related Posts in ".$category->cat_name." </h3>";
        $postlist = get_posts('category='.$category->cat_name);
            foreach ($postlist as $post) :
                $catpostid = $post->ID;
                    if (in_category($category->cat_name) && ($catpostid != $postid)) { ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <?php }
            endforeach;
      }
?>
```

Can anyone help me add a post count argument to this? I've been trying to modify this for hours and I keep breaking it. All I need is the ability to control how many posts show up. Sorry, but I'm a complete nub when it comes to coding anything in PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the numberposts argument to get_posts() as well as your category... I've listed a couple ideas here on the $args = line, only allow 10 posts, orders by title ascending, from your category name. Fully untested of course, but feel free to play around with it!

```
<?php
  $postid = $post->ID;
  foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
   echo "<h3>Related Posts in ".$category->cat_name." </h3>";
   $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title', 'category' => $category->cat_name );
   $postlist = get_posts( $args );
   foreach ($postlist as $post) :
   $catpostid = $post->ID;
   if (in_category($category->cat_name) && ($catpostid != $postid)) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
   <?php }
   endforeach;
  } ?>
```

Comment: For a full list of the parameters you can pass to get_posts also take a look at the Wordpress documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Tried the code you provided, it didn't break or give any errors. But the odd thing is when I dropped the numberposts to 4 from 10, it only shows 1 related posts. 

There are 3 posts inside this test category, so it should show two related posts. As I stated above 4 posts and below only show 1 related posts, but 5-10 and I'm assuming any number above 10 shows 2 posts.

Any ideas?